# How to dynamically set initial value for a vanilla javascript MVC component?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I'm trying out a MVC approach to using vanilla JS components.

However, with the following setup I can't update the view depending on the model.

Everything is going well until the code reaches the view constructor. There, the view will have to be updated depending on a value specified in the model, as pushed through via the controller.

I do get the value through. However, the HTML template isn't updated.

Now the following code example shows a lot of boilerplate code. That's necessary to get a functionally working example. The pain point seems to be mainly in the `TestView` class.

```js
// unrelated helper function
const stringToHTMLCollection = function(string) {
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  string = string.trim(); // Never return a text node of whitespace as the result
  template.innerHTML = string;
  return template.content.children;
}

class TestModel {
 constructor(data) {
   this._firstValue = data.first;
  }
  get firstValue() {
   return this._firstValue;
  }
}

class TestController {
 constructor(model) {
   this.model = model;
  }
  get firstValue() {
   return this.model.firstValue;
  }
}


class TestView {

 static htmlString() {
   return `<div>
       <ul>
         <li id="first-list-item">0</li>
          <li>0</li>
        </ul>
      </div>`
  }

 constructor(controller) {
   this.controller = controller;
   this.testView = TestView.htmlString();
    this.list = stringToHTMLCollection(this.testView)[0];
    this.listItems = this.list.getElementsByTagName('li');
    this.init();
  }
  
  init() {
    // this is going well, output: 100
   console.log(this.controller.firstValue);
     
    Object.entries(this.listItems).forEach(([key, price]) => {
      if (price.id === 'first-list-item') {
        price.innerHTML = this.controller.firstValue;
      }
    });

    // this is going well, output element with innerText of 100
    console.log(this.listItems[0]);
  }
  
  renderInto(targetNode) {
   if(!targetNode) return;
    targetNode.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', this.testView);
  }
}

const resultElement = document.getElementById('result');

function testComponent(pricing) {
 const testModel = new TestModel(pricing),
        testController = new TestController(testModel);
 return new TestView(testController);
}

const pricing = {
 first: 100,
  second: 200
}

testComponent(pricing).renderInto(result);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I guess the stringToHTMLCollection actually creates a new instance. Using it as a definition in the constructor and then returning that one after the init solves it.

Example:

```js
// unrelated helper function
const stringToHTMLCollection = function(string) {
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  string = string.trim(); // Never return a text node of whitespace as the result
  template.innerHTML = string;
  return template.content.children;
}

class TestModel {
 constructor(data) {
   this._firstValue = data.first;
  }
  get firstValue() {
   return this._firstValue;
  }
}

class TestController {
 constructor(model) {
   this.model = model;
  }
  get firstValue() {
   return this.model.firstValue;
  }
}


class TestView {

 static htmlString() {
   return `<div>
       <ul>
         <li id="first-list-item">0</li>
          <li>0</li>
        </ul>
      </div>`
  }

 constructor(controller) {
   this.controller = controller;
   this.testView = TestView.htmlString();
    this.html = stringToHTMLCollection(this.testView);
    this.list = this.html[0];
    this.listItems = this.list.getElementsByTagName('li');
    this.init();
  }
  
  init() {
    // this is going well, output: 100
   console.log(this.controller.firstValue);
     
    Object.entries(this.listItems).forEach(([key, price]) => {
      if (price.id === 'first-list-item') {
        price.innerHTML = this.controller.firstValue;
      }
    });

    // this is going well, output element with innerText of 100
    console.log(this.listItems[0]);
  }
  
  renderInto(targetNode) {
   if(!targetNode) return;
    targetNode.insertAdjacentElement('beforeend', this.html[0]);
  }
}

const resultElement = document.getElementById('result');

function testComponent(pricing) {
 const testModel = new TestModel(pricing),
        testController = new TestController(testModel);
 return new TestView(testController);
}

const pricing = {
 first: 100,
  second: 200
}

testComponent(pricing).renderInto(result);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```